# Problem 5 IMC 2021 (eigenvalues of a matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, contest-math

This problem is from IMC $2021$.

> Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix and suppose that for every positive integer $m$ there exists a real symmetric matrix $B_m$ such that $$2021B_m=A^m+B_m^2.$$ Prove that $|\det A|\leq1$.

In the official solution of this problem it is proven first that $A$ is symmetric as well, so $A$ is diagonalizable.

This is the part that I do not understand of that solution: If we fix $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$, there exists an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $B_m$ such that $2021\mu = \lambda^m+\mu^2$.

I know that there exist invertible matrices $P,Q$ and diagonal matrices $C,D$ (whose elements of the diagonal are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B_m$, respectively) such that $A=PCP^{-1}$ and $B_m=QDQ^{-1}$. It follows that $PC^mP^{-1} = Q(2021D-D^2)Q^{-1}$. Why are $C^m$ and $2021D-D^2$ equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ be the eigenvalues of $B_m$ (repeated according to their multiplicity, so these are the diagonal elements of the matrix $D$.)
Then the eigenvalues of $G_m=2021B_m-B_m^2$ are $2021\mu_j-\mu_j^2$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. Indeed,  $B_m=QDQ^{-1}$ implies that
$G_m=Q(2021 D-D^2) Q^{-1}$. The hypothesis was that $G_m=A$, so there is no need to find another $P$ for $A$; the same $Q$ will do.

The conceptual reason is that $B_m$ and $G_m$ commute, so they can be diagonalized simultaneously.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization

Comment: Why is it important that $B_m$ and $G_m$ commute?

Comment: @LordVader Because that means that your $P$ and your $Q$ may be taken to be equal. Which means we can simplify $B$ and $A$ to both be diagonal.

Comment: This is the conceptual reason they have the same eigenvectors. In this special case we can check it directly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization